# is it possible to register multicast IP addresses?

Tags: ipv4, multicast, standardisation

topic : IPv4 multicast addresses as per [IANA docs](http://www.iana.org/assignments/multicast-addresses/multicast-addresses.xhtml)

Is it possible to register these addresses or they are reserved like 0.0.0.0/8, 10.0.0.0/8, 127.0.0.0/24, etc... ?

When we read a specific multicast group is used by a software/vendor, is it possible the vendor is the owner of the address space including the multicast ip, or never possible ?

NOTE : I don't want to register one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are certain blocks of multicast address space reserved for certain things. For example, the `224.0.0.0/24` block is reserved for local network control (Link-Local), and multicast addresses in this block should not be forwarded to another LAN, even with multicast routing enabled.

See the IANA [*IPv4 Multicast Address Space Registry*](https://www.iana.org/assignments/multicast-addresses/multicast-addresses.xhtml) and [*IPv6 Multicast Address Space Registry*](https://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv6-multicast-addresses/ipv6-multicast-addresses.xhtml).

The Ad-Hoc blocks are used to register/reserve addresses for various functions, but it requires "*Expert Review, IESG Approval, or Standards Action*." Basically, you need to get a consensus. The best way would be to get an RFC approved, but notice that some companies have registered multicast address space. For example, `224.0.19.0-224.0.19.63` is registered to the Walt Disney Company.

Comment: I understand your good answer. But I don't understand why http://whois.arin.net/rest/ip/224.0.19.0.txt says "IANA Special Use" and not "Walt Disney Company" as per IANA IPv4 Multicast Address Space Registry

Comment: Please : except this block "Local Network Control Block (224.0.0.0 - 224.0.0.255 (224.0.0/24))", IP into all the other blocks can be registered as public ?

Comment: The Ad-Hoc blocks are the ones designed to be registered. You could register something in Local Network Control, or Internetwork Control if you get a consensus for those types of protocols. For example, creating a new routing protocol that uses multicast, you could register addresses in the Internetwork Control Block.

Comment: The whois is only telling you that the address belongs to IANA because multicast cannot be used across the public Internet.

Comment: Ron, I don't understand "multicast cannot be used across the public internet". Multicast is used across internet, for example with the Mbone

Comment: Regarding ownsership of the addresses : in the multicast address space, only IP into this block can be registered as public ? "Internetwork Control Block (224.0.1.0 - 224.0.1.255 (224.0.1/24))"

Comment: Multicast routing is very different than unicast routing. Currently, the ISPs that make up the public Internet do not route multicast (a form of broadcast, and you cannot route broadcast). The multicast registry exists to try to bring order to private networks. Without it, application designers would clash and applications would interfere with each other (they still do because programmers ignore the registry). I have seen in [so] where a programmer was using the multicast address for OSPF. That would really mess up a LAN.

Comment: You could register a multicast group address in just about any of the blocks, but multicast simply cannot be routed on the public Internet at this time. There are multiple ways to route multicast, and you would need the cooperation of every ISP. It would mean carrying a lot more traffic, and they simply will not do that, nor agree on a method. For example, DM requires that every router send ever DM multicast packet to every interface, and that would cripple the public Internet.

Comment: In order to send multicast traffic across the public Internet, you need to create tunnels in which to send the multicast packets. Tunnels require that the tuunel endpoint be specifically set up. This is useful for companies that want to send multicast between sites within a company, or to vendor, customer, or partner companies that have prearranged this. You simply cannot sent packets addresses to multicast destinations on the public Internet as the ISPs will drop those packets as bogons.